# Setting pointer variable from function C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

how would I go about adjusting a char* pointer from another function.  Right now Im in my code, it looks like the addresses are syncing so im feeling im doing something wrong please help.

```
void adjustVar(char* pointer, size_t i) {
   //pointer address at this point = 0x00000000
   pointer = new char[i];
   //pointer address at this point = 0x003db708
}

int main(void) {
   char* p = nullptr;
   size_t size = 5;
   //p Address at this point 0x00000000
   newBuffer(p, size);
   //p Address at this point 0x00000000
   delete[] p;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? R Sahu is correct, but if you don't know the answer to this question you probably don't want to be using `new` yet either. Consider using `std::vector<char>` which saves you from having to `delete` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of the following options:

Option 1: Return the allocated memory from `adjustVar`.

```
char* adjustVar(size_t i) {
   char* pointer = new char[i];
   return pointer;
}
```

Option 2: Use a reference to a pointer.

```
void adjustVar(char*& pointer, size_t i) {
   //pointer address at this point = 0x00000000
   pointer = new char[i];
   //pointer address at this point = 0x003db708
}
```

Comment: perfect that's just what i was looking for. Thanks